# c# Deserialize nested Json returns null

Tags: c#, json, serialization, null, nested

I am trying to deserialize a nester Json but it keeps returning a null value.

json:

```
{  
   "count":1,
   "page":1,
   "last_page":1,
   "total":1,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "data_id":24,
         "name":"Sealed Package of Snowballs",
         "rarity":1,
         "restriction_level":0,
         "img":"https:\/\/render.guildwars2.com\/file\/1D05D1EE04E16E69710E1EAB11AC466BBF105778\/219347.png",
         "type_id":3,
         "sub_type_id":2,
         "price_last_changed":"2015-04-02 14:57:33 UTC",
         "max_offer_unit_price":91,
         "min_sale_unit_price":120,
         "offer_availability":20969,
         "sale_availability":18702,
         "sale_price_change_last_hour":0,
         "offer_price_change_last_hour":0
      }
   ]
}
```

I can deserialize Count, page, last_page and total without problems. But everything nested 1 level lower returns a null value.

This is the deserialize code:

```
public Result GetApi(string url)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
                    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    return serializer.Deserialize<Result>(jsonReader);
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
                using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                    String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // log errorText
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And these are the classes:

```
 public class Result
    {
        public int data_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int rarity { get; set; }
        public int restriction_level { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
        public int type_id { get; set; }
        public int sub_type_id { get; set; }
        public string price_last_changed { get; set; }
        public int max_offer_unit_price { get; set; }
        public int min_sale_unit_price { get; set; }
        public int offer_availability { get; set; }
        public int sale_availability { get; set; }
        public int sale_price_change_last_hour { get; set; }
        public int offer_price_change_last_hour { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int last_page { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    }
```

Why does a nested Json return null value?

Comment: Shouldn't you be deserializing it into a `RootObject`?

Comment: In the RootObject i can not access the correct properties, in Result i can.

Comment: you have to drill into it: `data.results[0].name`;  Look at the classes: a RootObject containing an array/List of results which is where Name is

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, that did the trick and now also understand why. Thanks a lot, sorry for this stupid silly mistake of mine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
               var root = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);
```

Also, the results are returned as an array, so you might have more than one returned.

If you are sure that no more than one `Result` is going to be returned, you can do:

```
               var result = root.results.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: But in RootObject i can not access the properties like name etc. Only the first level, not the second nester levle.

Comment: Yes, but those properties aren't at the first level in the JSON.  To deserialize that JSON, your c# classes need to correspond to its structure.

Comment: I've got it now, thanks for the help!